# Problema no get no método Node Express

Tags: node.js

Estou tentando lista registro do menu no meu banco de dados no MongoDB e não estou tendo sucesso, porém quando listo os registros de Restaurant tenho sucesso, todas as duas coleções estão na mesma base de dados, por que será que isso está acontecendo?

Esse é meu método que listar todos os restaurant

```
exports.get = (req, res, next) => {
    Restaurant
    .find({})
    .then(data => {
        res.status(200).send(data);
    }).catch(e => {
        res.status(401).send(e);   
    })

};
```

E esse é o método para listar os registros do menu

```
exports.getMenus = (req, res, next) => {
    Menu
    .find({})
    .then(data => {
        res.status(200).send(data);
    }).catch(e => {
        res.status(401).send(e);   
    })

};
```

Comment: Aparece algum erro? A variável `exports` está sendo exportada no módulo?

Answer (score 0):

Parece que `getMenus` é um método não definido pelo sistema, mas `get` sim.

O que você acha de fazer assim?:

```
getMenus = exports.get = (req, res, next) => {
    Menu
    .find({})
    .then(data => {
        res.status(200).send(data);
    }).catch(e => {
        res.status(401).send(e);
    })
};
```